# Добавление текста в Listview с другого активити с помощью Intent (Android)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

Хочу, чтобы текст из Edittext с одного активити был включен в Listview, который находится в другом активити. Написал код, вроде должно заработать, да ни черта.... Никаких ошибок не выдает, но после того, как я набираю текст и нажимаю кнопку, приложение тупо закрывается....

Буду крайне благодарен за помощь.

```
Listview id = listView;
Button id = button;
Edittext id = setText;
```

Вот код.

Это MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText setText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("text", setText.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Это второй активити, где находится `listview`

```
public class Intent_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map;
    final String TEXT = "text";
    String text = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intent_activity);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Intent_Activity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        data.add(map);

        String[] from = {TEXT};
        int[] to = {R.id.textView};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item, from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }
        text = data.getStringExtra("text");
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(TEXT, text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в `LogCat`, там будет стек-трейс исключения.

Comment: выложи проект этого на гит хабе тогда может я решу эту проблему